# Mac waking for network access (ARPT) even though options disabled in preferences

Tags: sleep-wake

My mac just woke up on its own. Checked the logs:

```
syslog |grep -i "Wake reason"


Jan  2 00:44:51 macbooks-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] <Notice>: 
     ARPT: 451153.297249: ARPT: Wake Reason: Wake on TCP Data
Jan  2 00:44:51 macbooks-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] <Notice>: 
      [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason
      Wake reason: Host (0x01)
```

However I had disabled the "wake on network activity":

[image]
[image]

So then why is it waking up?  I am on El Capitan.